# How to connect Apple Magic Mouse to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mouse

iPhone 6s Plus, iOS 10.3.2 public beta 5. Is it possible to connect Apple Magic Mouse 2 to my iPhone without jailbreaking? I've managed to connect Apple Magic Keyboard 2 to iPhone earlier.

Comment: What would you expect to happen (or be able to do) once the mouse is connected?

Comment: @patrix You know, I expected to play Modern Combat 5 with keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jailbreaking, iOS does not have mouse support.